# How do I convert my MySQL database so I can edit it right in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I want to edit my table like when you install wordpress. But I can't. Linked picture is of my Database

This is my non editable Database:
[image: This is my non editable Database]

That's what I want it to look like:
[image: That's what I want it to look like]

Sorry it's my first time working with mysql databases and I have no clue what I'm doing

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68940560/edit) to show your schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have the capability to edit rows in phpMyAdmin, it has to be possible to identify those rows reliably, so that phpMyAdmin knows which row to actually update.

Therefore you need to have a primary or a unique key.

The columns `name` or `shortcode` look like candidates to which you could apply this constraint.

Which one has to be the primary key and which one should be unique, depends on how you reference (or plane to reference) these entires in another table.